# Glitch in Excel's MATCH?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula bellow returns `#N/A` but I was expecting `3`( because the 3rd row contains smallest value that is equal or greater that 4).

`=MATCH(4,M37:M41,-1)`

Contents of `M37:M41`

```
1
3
6
12
24
```

Does anyone know the reason why? Or better yet how to get that `3` out of this or similar formula?

UPDATE: I changed MATCH to look for various numbers, the only value for match that returns anything other than error is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match will return a `#N/A` error for the following reason.

> -1    MATCH finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value. The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed
>   in descending order

If you switch to the descending order, the formula works.

[image]